# Remove Add to Cart Button from MyStile Theme in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have difficulty doing this even after following instructions of how to do it. I don't know if the structure of `woocommerce` have changed since the below snippet was given.

Below is the code I tried using to remove the `Add to cart` button in the `Homeapage` and `Shop page`.

Mind you, this was pasted in the `Theme Functions (functions.php)` and I use `MyStile Theme`.

I was able to remove the `Add to Cart` button from the single page but not the `homepage and shop page`.

**Code**

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
}
add_action('init', 'remove_loop_button');
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code. Put it in your `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

To Remove “Add to Cart” button all you need to do is paste the following lines of code in your `functions.php` file located inside your theme’s directory.

```
//remove "Add to Cart" button on product listing page in WooCommerce

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
}
```

Comment: Use the above code to remove Add to cart . it must work

Comment: I tried it but it did not, dunno is the class name in MyStile theme is different though.

Comment: You can always CSS and add diplay-none to hide elements.

Comment: That will likely remove the button from all pages in the website.